# Javascript get last word after # symbol

Tags: javascript, url, get

My URL is like

> http://mysite.in/some_path/some_file.php#section1

Now i want to get the value `"section1"` which is after `#` symbol in the URL

i first tried using PHP ,

```
$last_value = explode('#',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$last = $last_value[sizeof($last_value)-1];
```

But it echo

> /some_path/some_file.php

Later i found that it can't be achieved using PHP .

Kindly help in guiding how to get the last value in the URL after `#` symbol using `JavaScript`

**EDIT:**

The Hint of @Perumal93 from the comment helped me to search for method using JavaScript

The following URL helped me achieving that by using JavaScript

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/23563760/3185747

Comment: The fragment of the URI is not sent to the server.

Comment: Not possible. URL Fragments does not get sent to the server.

Comment: What is with this variable $urlArray, I think you need to replace $urlArray with $last_value.

Comment: URL Fragments will not be sent to server. It can only be handled by JavaScript if you want to make it with browser. The JavaScript code is  `var hash = window.location.hash;`. This line of code gets you hash from the URL.

Comment: @Rahul sorry for that , edit made in question . kindly see that mate

Comment: @Perumal93 let me try that and get back here mate

Comment: @RajaGopal Check the dupe bro. It's not possible.

Comment: @Perumal93 Thanks a lot for the hint mate , Javascript worked for me and i added that as edit in the question.

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for the link mate , however i found that it can be achieved using JavaScript and hence i added that as edit in my question. Now i guess this might be helpful for persons who search relevant questions