# How to save a users input from a javascript pop up form in to a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I dont know if this is possible but i want to ask if its possible to save a users input from a javascript pop up form into a php variable. For example in this code provided by w3schools the user input is displayed on the screen, instead of this how do i save it to a variable in php. The source code of the example is the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Prompt</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var txt;
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");
    if (person == null || person == "") {
        txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
    } else {
        txt = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What i have to learn in order to be able to do that?
Thanks in regards

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I store JavaScript variable output into a PHP variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662927/how-can-i-store-javascript-variable-output-into-a-php-variable)

Comment: i want to save the this javascript variable in a php variable so i can pass it in a php function

Comment: I tried the following link that you provided but it seems that it works differently if the js variavle is in a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is a client-side language and PHP is a server-side language.
By using a HTTP form you can instruct HTML to send the input to a PHP file (form data).

You can also transport data between front-end and back-end by using AJAX.
Using AJAX you can choose to store you data in a JSON file structure.

Learn topics in following order.

- HTML form and command set to send to PHP.
- PHP - How to receive form input data & handling PHP variables.
- AJAX
- JSON (optional).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var txt;
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");
    if (person == null || person == "") {
        txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
    } else {
        txt = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
    // Prepare object with data
    var data = {data: txt};
    var url = 'submit.php'
    xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
    }
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

And in your `submit.php` you can capture post data using following snippet

```
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonData = json_decode($postData);
$key = 'data';
$data = $jsonData->$key;
```

You will have data in `$data` variable

Comment: I used this source code and then i try to echo the variable data but i am not getting anything

Comment: Are you getting anything when you echo `$postData`

Comment: No mate , i am not getting anything from this either

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly, you would like to push a variable from JS to PHP ? 
The only way to achieve this is by using `http request`.

Here is a link that may help you :

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_php.asp